# Can I use :has selector inside another :has selector?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to make it so that whenever someone hovers over class .a (or .b) in .list, change styling of icons with same class.

```
<div class="icons">
  <a class="a"></a>
  <a class="b"></a>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <span class="a">A</span>
  <span class="b">B</span>
</div>
```

I have tried the following, but didnt work.

```
icons:has(.a:hover) .a {
  color: blue;
}
```

Comment: Your question does not match your code (there is no "`:has` selector inside another `:has` selector").

Comment: `icons:has(.a:hover) ~ .list .a` ?

Comment: `icons` is a class, so you should use `.icons`

Answer (score 1):

Besides your code not actually implementing the code in question, it has a multitude of other problems:

- You are selecting `<icons>`, which does not exist
- There is nothing in `.icons .a` to hover over
- You are using a descendant selector, selecting the same `.a` outside of `:has` as the one inside

Once you correct these, you can see `:hover` inside `:has` works:

```css
.icons:has(.a:hover) + .list .a {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="icons">
  <a class="a">X</a>
  <a class="b">Y</a>
</div>

<div class="list">
  <span class="a">A</span>
  <span class="b">B</span>
</div>
```

Now if you float your cursor over `X`, `A` will become blue.

However, at the time of this answer, `:has` itself is not supported on some browsers; most notably, it is not enabled on Firefox by default.